# Installed TensorFlow in Windows-Native but returns 0 in verifying GPU setup?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu, miniconda

I am trying to install TensorFlow-GPU in order to use the GPU when using Jupyter Notebook for my machine learning project. I followed the step-by-step instructions written in the TensorFlow site (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1) but when I reach the last step of verifying the GPU setup, it returns 0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

For context, the GPU my laptop has is an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU (with an AMD Radeon Graphics CPU). As mentioned, I followed all the steps in the TensorFlow site so I installed the latest NVIDIA GPU Driver, CUDA Toolkit 11.8, and cuDNN SDK 8.6.0 (all installed). I'm running on Windows 10 and have also downloaded the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019 (x86) - 14.29.30139. Made sure long paths are also enabled. Then downloaded Miniconda, created the conda environment (tf), then did the GPU setup and installed Tensorflow in said conda environment.

Here's what it looks like when I tried to verify the CPU and GPU setup:

> (tf) C:\Users[Username]>python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
> 2023-07-25 17:25:13.098180: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> 2023-07-25 17:25:13.452037: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3475 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
> tf.Tensor(1081.4866, shape=(), dtype=float32)

> (tf) C:\Users[Username]>python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
> [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

[Here's an image to show what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnUKS.png). I was expecting to see at the very least a "1" in the config list but it says GPU:0.

Comment: There is no error message, Tensorflow finds your GPU (`device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU`) as GPU 0 (it starts counting at 0).

Answer (score 0):

> (tf) C:\Users[Username]>python -c "import tensorflow as tf;
> print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))" 2023-07-25
> 17:25:13.098180: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193]
> This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network
> Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in
> performance-critical operations: AVX AVX2 To enable them in other
> operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> 2023-07-25 17:25:13.452037: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3475 MB memory: ->
> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id:
> 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6 tf.Tensor(1081.4866, shape=(),
> dtype=float32)
>
> (tf) C:\Users[Username]>python -c "import tensorflow as tf;
> print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
> [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

The messages indicate that TensorFlow has detected your NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, and the GPU is available for computations.

**Here's a breakdown highlighting key elements:**

**1.** The message **Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0** confirms that TensorFlow has created a GPU device.

**2.** The line name: **NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU** indicates that TensorFlow has identified your GPU correctly.

**3.** The output **[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]** from the second command shows that TensorFlow recognizes the GPU as a physical device.

The result of your GPU verification indicates that TensorFlow-GPU is installed correctly and is able to utilize your GPU for computations.